# How to update dynamic editext values into nested json array in android?

Tags: android

This is my json data I have created ui design using this json string but by the time of updating I am confused about this how to correctly get `EditText` values and how to update

```
{
"SingleExtras": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "name": "size",
        "isEnabled": 1,
        "values": [{
                "extraId": 30,
                "objId": "Gb39Rpmdl9",
                "extraName": "Small",
                "extraPrice": 15,
                "currency": "Aed",
                "isEnabled": 1
            },
            {
                "extraId": 30,
                "objId": "kknwBtS9zJ",
                "extraName": "Medium",
                "extraPrice": 18,
                "currency": "Aed",
                "isEnabled": 0
            },
            {
                "extraId": 30,
                "objId": "d5YfEGAgMt",
                "extraName": "Large",
                "extraPrice": 20,
                "currency": "Aed",
                "isEnabled": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 5,
        "name": "Milk",
        "isEnabled": 1,
        "values": [{
                "extraId": 30,
                "objId": "8obBCWDXbh",
                "extraName": "LowFatMilk",
                "extraPrice": 0,
                "currency": "Aed",
                "isEnabled": 1
            },
            {
                "extraId": 31,
                "objId": "CC629INXuP",
                "extraName": "FullFatMilk",
                "extraPrice": 0,
                "currency": "Aed",
                "isEnabled": 1
            }

        ]
    }
],
"Extras": [{
    "extraId": 5,
    "objId": "PxDQX3LGU2",
    "extraName": "ExtraShot",
    "extraPrice": 5,
    "currency": "Aed",
    "isEnabled": 1
}]
```

}

I'm using the code below to get the modified `EditText` values in that

```
 for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
            pricelist.add(allEds.get(i).getText().toString().trim());
            priceidslist.add(allEds.get(i).getId());
        }
```

This is nested array function here in loop I'm getting array index{0,1,2,0,1,2,0} like this i have all editetxt prices list by using im not able to update index position values mismatching

```
  public void jsonarray(JSONArray arry){
    try {

        for (int j = 0; j < arry.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject rw = arry.getJSONObject(j);
            String extraId = rw.optString("extraId");
            String objId = rw.optString("objId");
            String extraName = rw.optString("extraName");
            String extraPrice = rw.optString("extraPrice");
            String currenc = rw.optString("currency");
            String chksts = rw.optString("isEnabled");

            if (namechklist.contains(extraName)) {
                rw.put("isEnabled", "1");
            }
            if (nameunchklist.contains(extraName)) {
                rw.put("isEnabled", "0");
            }
            if(allnames.contains(extraName)){

               rw.put("extraPrice", pricelist.get(j));
            }

            Log.d("res", "jsonarray:loop "+arry.toString());
        }

        Log.d("res", "jsonarray: "+arry.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Anyone please suggest me which way is better to achieve this logic correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject row = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String itemid = row.optString("id");
                JSONArray arry = row.getJSONArray("values");
                if(i == 0){

                }
                else{
                    final int ar = arry.length();
                    final int tot = g + ar ;
                    int h = 0;
                    for (int j = g ; j < tot; j++) {

                        JSONObject rw = arry.getJSONObject(h);
                        String extraName = rw.optString("extraName");
                        String extraId = rw.optString("extraId");
                        if(namechklist.size() > 0){
                            if(namechklist.contains(extraName)){
                                rw.put("isEnabled","1");
                            }
                        }
                        if(nameunchklist.size()>0){
                            if(nameunchklist.contains(extraName)){
                                rw.put("isEnabled","0");
                            }
                        }
                        if(j >= arry.length()){

                        }else{

                           String gh = String.valueOf(priceidslist.get(j));
                           if(gh.equals(extraId)){
                               rw.put("extraPrice",pricelist.get(j));
                           }

                        }
                        h++;
                    }
                    g = arry.length();
                }

            }
            Log.d("chk", "res:last "+jsonArray.toString());
        }
        JSONArray extraArray = obj.getJSONArray("Extras");
        for (int i = 0; i < extraArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject rw = extraArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String extraName = rw.optString("extraName");
            String extraId = rw.optString("extraId");
            if(exnamechklist.size() > 0){
                if(exnamechklist.contains(extraName)){
                    rw.put("isEnabled","1");
                }
            }
            if(exnameunchklist.size()>0){
                if(exnameunchklist.contains(extraName)){
                    rw.put("isEnabled","0");
                }
            }
        }
```

*I just changed for loop condition and changed format of getting json values now its working fine*